# How to make a sidebar that doesn't have to reload when change the main content?

Tags: html

I have a fixed sidebar that is working and I like but I don't want it to have to reload every time I want to change the the main content. I also just don't want to have to copy and paste it into every content page over and over again when I want to make changes. My thoughts is there possibly a way to make the side bar and content separate but display them at the same time?

Comment: check about `frame` or `iframe`

Answer (score -1):

if you want them to remain on the same page I recommend you to try a 1 page approach or [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) were you use `#` to target a specific id, for example :

```html
<body>
<header>
    <ul class = "nav" style = "display:flex;list-style:none;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;">
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#homepage"> Home </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#products"> Products </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#orderstatus"> Order status </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#support"> Customer Support </a> <li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section id="homepage">
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
</section>


<section id="products">
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
</section>


<section id="orderstatus">
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
</section>


<section id="support">
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
</section>

</body>
```